# Why event listener isn't working even though I selected right element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, addeventlistener

I added an event listener to the "learn more" div and it doesn't work. When I inspected that div element and went to the "Event Listeners" tab, it shows that it has the event listener attached to it. I thought the "vert-gradient" div (see code) prevents it from being triggered, but when I deleted it, the problem remained.

```js
let lms = document.querySelectorAll(".lm");
lms.forEach((lm) => {
  console.log(lm); //this works
  lm.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("click!"); //this doesn't work!
  });
});
```

```css
.border {
  width: 354px;
  height: 404px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(212, 119, 66, 1) 81%);
  border-radius: 27px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.prod {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #0000ff;
}

.prod h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
  bottom: 78px;
}

.prod h3 {
  color: #d47742;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  bottom: 32px;
}

.prod h2,
.prod h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

.vert-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.7) 55%,
    rgb(19, 19, 19) 84%
  );
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.lm {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.lm span {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.lm img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" cat="b">
  <div class="prod">
    <h2>Bread</h2>
    <h3>1,50€</h3>
    <div class="lm">
      <span>Learn More</span>
    </div>
    <div class="vert-gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to remove the "border" div but the problem remained. I tried to attach the event listener to the "prod" div, but it isn't triggered either. `event.preventDefault();` doesn't do anything.

Comment: By the looks of things your CSS is causing the problems. Adding layers of `pointer-events: none;` isn't helping, and neither is the z-indexing I don't think. Aside: your `span` should probably (ideally) be a button.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this HTML structure and CSS . It's a bit odd.

But first-of-all you are using `pointer-events:none` on both of your item's ancestors. Which disables the click event on the `lm` child.

Second, you use `z-index` on your ancestors which is lower than 0 and lower than the `vert-gradient` z-index. That means, the `vert-gradient` will go on top.

Without any other context on what you are trying to achieve. Here's a working example that shows exactly why what I said above is making your element not clickable.

Again, you should rethink your CSS and HTML structure because the ones you have are not correct at all.

```js
let lms = document.querySelectorAll(".lm");
lms.forEach((lm) => {
  console.log(lm); //this works
  lm.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); // add this if you don't want ev bubbling up
    console.log("click!"); //this doesn't work!
  });
});
```

```css
.border {
  width: 354px;
  height: 404px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(212, 119, 66, 1) 81%);
  border-radius: 27px;
  position: relative;
}

.prod {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background: #0000ff;
}

.prod h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
  bottom: 78px;
}

.prod h3 {
  color: #d47742;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  bottom: 32px;
}

.prod h2,
.prod h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

.vert-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.7) 55%,
    rgb(19, 19, 19) 84%
  );
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.lm {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.lm span {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.lm img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" cat="b">
  <div class="prod">
    <h2>Bread</h2>
    <h3>1,50€</h3>
    <div class="lm">
      <span>Learn More</span>
    </div>
    <div class="vert-gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a CSS problem, preventing the click from hitting the intended target. I started paring it away til I got to this working example:

```js
let lms = document.querySelectorAll(".lm");
lms.forEach((lm) => {
  console.log(lm); //this works
  lm.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click!"); //this doesn't work!
  });
});
```

```css
.border {
  width: 354px;
  height: 404px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(212, 119, 66, 1) 81%);
  border-radius: 27px;
}

.prod {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #0000ff;
}

.prod h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.prod h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
 }

.lm{
 background: rgba(212, 119, 66, 1);
}

.lm-text{
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div class="border" cat="b">
    <div class="prod">
      <h2>Bread</h2>
      <h3>1,50€</h3>
      <div class="lm">
        <span class="lm-text">Learn More</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```